# Migration Tool: "Concurrent modification from setup pages"

Tags: migration-tool

I'm trying to deploy changes from one sandbox to another using the Migration Tool, but I keep getting the following error: **Error: objects/Contact.object(263,13): Concurrent modification from setup pages**

What causes this error, and how can I deal with it?

- I've verified that my `Contact.object` file is well-formed and valid
- I have *not* been making any other changes simultaneously through the setup pages or by any other means
- The location specified (263,13) is the start of a `<fields>` element for a custom field in the middle of the definition file.  This picklist field already exists in the destination environment, but I am changing some of its values

Comment: Never seen this before, and I have deployed code using the Migration tool thousands of times. If it still happens after a few hours, you're probably going to want to file a case. Please update this question with the solution if/when you find it.

Comment: I'm still seeing this on the AccountContactRole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior appears to have been caused by a [known platform bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SuvSAAS).  According to SFDC, the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Interesting...my error wasn't with a dependent picklist.  Just a plain old picklist.

Comment: Ditto, still getting this for a plain vanilla account picklist.  Changing the api versions as suggested in the bug report as a workaround wasn't any help.

Answer (score 4):

We just experienced this same issue.  We saw which field was causing the problem by the IDE reporting the error. The target org had a picklist field that was modified later than the source and had different values.  We changed the target picklist values to match the source and the deployment then succeeded.

Comment: I just saw this again as well; have logged a support case and will let you know what I learn.